# Omega and Panels: Is there a way to change "Omega XX column grid" layouts?

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I´m trying to work with the 3.x Omega version and Panels.
I´ve selected "Omega 16 column grid" at the panel´s layout category.
**Is there a way to change those layouts?**

***ie. There´s this "Two Column 8-8" and I need "Two Column 9-7"***
I´ve tried with "create custom layout", but can´t make that work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is update your region area in omega to adjust the # of columns each one takes up.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You mean to go back to the Omega layout configuration and just save it again? Because the # of columns were already configured before I installed panels...